# Finding non-consecutive increase over last 6 rows - alternatives to for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm looking for instances in my dataset where 4 of the last 6 samples show progressively increasing concentrations. I've worked out the logic of a series of if statements but I'm having trouble applying it to my data. I was planning on using cbind to attach the list to my dataset but the list ends up with 28 values and my data only has 24 rows.

I can't figure out what's happening with the for loop and have read that it's not a great way to do things anyways so I'm looking for alternatives.

EDIT: I've added some photos of two specific examples where suggested answers fail. The trouble seems to be that the "simple" solutions look for increases between consecutive points only. I'm looking for four points over each set of six that increase.

[Row 16 and Row 20 plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Z96.png)

Here is some of the data:

```
SAMPLE_DATE <- c("2013-08-02", "2014-06-13", "2015-09-03", "2016-06-12", "2016-09-27", "2017-05-30", "2017-05-30", "2017-09-14", "2017-09-14", "2017-12-02", "2018-03-29", "2018-06-05", "2018-10-19", "2019-02-27", "2019-06-04", "2019-08-28", "2019-10-22", "2020-02-04", "2020-06-06", "2020-08-26", "2020-10-23", "2021-02-01", "2021-06-15", "2021-08-03")
REPORT_RESULT_VALUE <- c(0.1470, 0.0623, 1.4600, 0.1810, 0.0509, 0.0801, 0.0801, 0.0999, 0.0980, 0.0820, 0.0698, 0.0884, 0.1060, 0.1010, 0.0984, 0.1050, 0.1100, 0.0980, 0.1000, 0.1090, 0.1050, 0.0662, 0.0944, 0.1220)
GWSubsetData <- data.frame(SAMPLE_DATE, REPORT_RESULT_VALUE)
```

And here is what I've attempted:

```
Groundwater_ST1 <- vector("list")
    
    for (i in seq_along(GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE)) {
        
        if (i >= 6) {
            
            a <- i-5
            b <- i-4
            c <- i-3
            d <- i-2
            e <- i-1
            
            #If i > 3 of first 5 samples
            if (sum(GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[i]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[a:e]) >= 3) {
                #If i>E and E > 2 of first 4 samples
                if ((GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[i]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[e]]) & 
                    (sum(GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[e]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[a:d]) > 2)) {
                    #if E>D and D > 1 of first 3 samples
                    if ((GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[e]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[d]]) &
                        (sum(GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[d]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[a:c]) >= 1)) {
                        Groundwater_ST1[i] = TRUE
                    #If E>C and C > 1 of first 2 sampels
                    }else if ((GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[e]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[c]]) & 
                              (sum(GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[c]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[a:b]) >= 1)) {
                        Groundwater_ST1[i] = TRUE
                    #If E>B and B>A
                    }else if ((GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[e]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[b]]) & 
                              (GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[b]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[a]])) {
                        Groundwater_ST1[i] = TRUE
                    }else{
                        Groundwater_ST1[i] = FALSE
                    }
                #If i>D and D > 2 of first 3 samples
                }else if ((GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[i]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[d]]) &
                          (sum(GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[d]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[a:c]) >= 2)) {
                    #If D>C and C > 1 of first 2 samples
                    if ((GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[d]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[c]]) & 
                        (sum(GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[c]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[a:b]) >= 1)) {
                        Groundwater_ST1[i] = TRUE
                    #If D>B and B>A
                    }else if ((GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[d]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[b]]) & 
                               (GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[b]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[a]])) {
                        Groundwater_ST1[i] = TRUE
                    }else{
                        Groundwater_ST1[i] = FALSE
                    }
                #If i > c > b > a
                }else if ((GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[i]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[c]]) &
                          (GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[c]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[b]) &
                          (GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[b]] > GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[[a]])) {
                    Groundwater_ST1[i] = TRUE
                }else{
                    Groundwater_ST1[i] = FALSE
                }
                
            }else{
                Groundwater_ST1[i] = FALSE                }
        }else{
            Groundwater_ST1[i] = FALSE
        }
    }
```

Comment: One potential wrinkle here is that your sample data has two dates (2017-05-30 and 2017-09-14) which appear twice each with different values, making it ambiguous (aside from the original row order) which order they should be evaluated upon. You'd potentially see (or miss) trends based on that ordering. It might be simplest to resolve that by taking the average per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Tricky! Here's a brute force tidyverse answer. Unless the data is many millions of rows long, this should be very performant, since its vectorized. Additional gains could be had by porting into `data.table` or `collapse` to get better performance for large numbers of groups.

My approach was to identify every possible ascending subset of four points within a window of 6. There are 15 of these patterns:

```
library(tidyverse)
subsets_to_try <- combinat::combn(1:6, 4) %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(combination = row_number(), 
         combo_pattern = paste0(V1,V2,V3,V4, sep=""), .before = 1)

#   combination combo_pattern V1 V2 V3 V4
#1            1          1234  1  2  3  4
#2            2          1235  1  2  3  5
#3            3          1236  1  2  3  6
#4            4          1245  1  2  4  5
#5            5          1246  1  2  4  6
#6            6          1256  1  2  5  6
#7            7          1345  1  3  4  5
#8            8          1346  1  3  4  6
#9            9          1356  1  3  5  6
#10          10          1456  1  4  5  6
#11          11          2345  2  3  4  5
#12          12          2346  2  3  4  6
#13          13          2356  2  3  5  6
#14          14          2456  2  4  5  6
#15          15          3456  3  4  5  6
```

For use below, we can save a version that is reshaped into long form. This produces a table that is 60 rows long (15 combinations x 4 positions).

```
subsets_long <- subsets_to_try %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(combination, combo_pattern), 
               names_to = "trend_num", names_prefix = "V", 
               names_transform = as.integer,
               values_to = "pos_in_window")
```

Now for the brute forcing. We can make 60 copies of each row, corresponding to each of the four positions an observation might have within the 15 sequences. We can then join the data to `subsets_long` so that each observation will now be situated at a particular position in a particular sequence.

We can rearrange the data so that each observation is in order within its sequence. Grouping within each possible sequence end date and combination, we can filter for just the situations where there is a 4-element increasing trend.

```
incr_sequences <- GW %>% 
  uncount(nrow(subsets_to_try), .id = "combination") %>%
  left_join(subsets_long) %>%
  mutate(SEQ_END = DATE_NUM - pos_in_window + 6) %>%
  arrange(SEQ_END, combination, pos_in_window) %>%
  group_by(SEQ_END, combination) %>%
  filter(sum(val > lag(val, default = -Inf)) == 4) %>%
  ungroup()
```

That's basically it. We might look at the identified sequences like this as a visual confirmation (I've filtered out the extreme point to clarify).

In case it's of any use downstream, I've preserved the observation that there are actually two ways to get a four-element ascending sequence ending row 16 or row 17, depending on whether they include 14 or 15. If you just need to know which windows have any working trend at all, you could look at `incr_sequences %>% distinct(SEQ_END)` to see it's just row 16 and 17 that work.

```
ggplot(incr_sequences, aes(DATE_NUM, val)) +
  geom_point(data = GW %>% filter(val < 0.5), color = "gray70") +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~interaction(SEQ_END, combo_pattern))
```

[image]

---

Original answer:

I think we could do this by counting the number of cumulative increases, then looking to see how the increases have changed over a window of 6 values.

```
library(dplyr)
GWSubsetData %>%
  mutate(increases = cumsum(REPORT_RESULT_VALUE > lag(REPORT_RESULT_VALUE, default = 0)),
         n_incr_last_6 = increases - lag(increases, 6, default = 0),
         flag = n_incr_last_6 >= 4)

   SAMPLE_DATE REPORT_RESULT_VALUE increases n_incr_last_6  flag
1   2013-08-02              0.1470         1             1 FALSE
2   2014-06-13              0.0623         1             1 FALSE
3   2015-09-03              1.4600         2             2 FALSE
4   2016-06-12              0.1810         2             2 FALSE
5   2016-09-27              0.0509         2             2 FALSE
6   2017-05-30              0.0801         3             3 FALSE
7   2017-05-30              0.0801         3             2 FALSE
8   2017-09-14              0.0999         4             3 FALSE
9   2017-09-14              0.0980         4             2 FALSE
10  2017-12-02              0.0820         4             2 FALSE
11  2018-03-29              0.0698         4             2 FALSE
12  2018-06-05              0.0884         5             2 FALSE
13  2018-10-19              0.1060         6             3 FALSE
14  2019-02-27              0.1010         6             2 FALSE
15  2019-06-04              0.0984         6             2 FALSE
16  2019-08-28              0.1050         7             3 FALSE
17  2019-10-22              0.1100         8             4  TRUE
18  2020-02-04              0.0980         8             3 FALSE
19  2020-06-06              0.1000         9             3 FALSE
20  2020-08-26              0.1090        10             4  TRUE
21  2020-10-23              0.1050        10             4  TRUE
22  2021-02-01              0.0662        10             3 FALSE
23  2021-06-15              0.0944        11             3 FALSE
24  2021-08-03              0.1220        12             4  TRUE
```

---

Base R equivalent:

```
GWSubsetData$incr = cumsum(c(1, diff(GWSubsetData$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE) > 0))
GWSubsetData$flag = (GWSubsetData$incr - lag(GWSubsetData$incr, 6, default = 0)) >= 4
```

Comment: This works in some cases but the trouble is that the increases need to be progressive but not consecutive. For example, Row 16 should be TRUE because rows 11, 12, 14, and 16 progressively increase. Row 20 should be false because even though there are technically four increases, there isn't any grouping of 4 points in that set of 6 that progressively increases.

Comment: This is still unclear to me, could you please add your desired output to the question?

Comment: Could you add more explanation about what a "progressive" increase means in this context?

Comment: I added an image of the two instances that I described. I need to find a way to look for 4 out of 6 samples that increase relative to one another (which is what your solution seems to be missing).

Comment: Interesting question! I've added a brute force answer, but I'd be very curious if there's a smarter way to do this w/o loops.

Comment: Very cool! I never would have would have come up with this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

## Edit:

I acknowledge that this approach doesn't lead to your expected result, but I wanted to post it in case it spurs you/others to come up with alternative approaches to brute forcing (if there are any...). Here, I'm defining "progressive increase" based on the direction of the slope of a linear relationship between date and val:

```
dat$date2 <- as.numeric(as.Date(dat$date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
w <- 6 # window

## With a loop
dat$slope <- NA
for(i in w:nrow(dat)){
  dat[i,"slope"] <- coef(lm(val ~ date2, data = dat[(i-w):i,]))[2]
}

## Without a loop
dat$slope2 <- NA
dat[w:nrow(dat), "slope2"] <- sapply(w:nrow(dat), function(i) coef(lm(val ~ date2, data = dat[(i-w):i,]))[2])
```

## Previous answer:

I'm assuming that if the change between a value and its previous value is greater than 0, there was an increase and if this happens 4 or more times within six consecutive values, your condition Groundwater_ST1 == TRUE:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)

dat %>%
  mutate(change = dat$val - lag(dat$val)) %>%
  mutate(incr = change > 0) %>%
  mutate(roll_sum = roll_sum(incr, 6, align = "right", fill = NA)) %>%
  mutate(Groundwater_ST1 = roll_sum >= 4)
```

result:

```
         date    val  change  incr roll_sum Groundwater_ST1
1  2013-08-02 0.1470      NA    NA       NA              NA
2  2014-06-13 0.0623 -0.0847 FALSE       NA              NA
3  2015-09-03 1.4600  1.3977  TRUE       NA              NA
4  2016-06-12 0.1810 -1.2790 FALSE       NA              NA
5  2016-09-27 0.0509 -0.1301 FALSE       NA              NA
6  2017-05-30 0.0801  0.0292  TRUE       NA              NA
7  2017-05-30 0.0801  0.0000 FALSE        2           FALSE
8  2017-09-14 0.0999  0.0198  TRUE        3           FALSE
9  2017-09-14 0.0980 -0.0019 FALSE        2           FALSE
10 2017-12-02 0.0820 -0.0160 FALSE        2           FALSE
11 2018-03-29 0.0698 -0.0122 FALSE        2           FALSE
12 2018-06-05 0.0884  0.0186  TRUE        2           FALSE
13 2018-10-19 0.1060  0.0176  TRUE        3           FALSE
14 2019-02-27 0.1010 -0.0050 FALSE        2           FALSE
15 2019-06-04 0.0984 -0.0026 FALSE        2           FALSE
16 2019-08-28 0.1050  0.0066  TRUE        3           FALSE
17 2019-10-22 0.1100  0.0050  TRUE        4            TRUE
18 2020-02-04 0.0980 -0.0120 FALSE        3           FALSE
19 2020-06-06 0.1000  0.0020  TRUE        3           FALSE
20 2020-08-26 0.1090  0.0090  TRUE        4            TRUE
21 2020-10-23 0.1050 -0.0040 FALSE        4            TRUE
22 2021-02-01 0.0662 -0.0388 FALSE        3           FALSE
23 2021-06-15 0.0944  0.0282  TRUE        3           FALSE
24 2021-08-03 0.1220  0.0276  TRUE        4            TRUE
```

data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  date =c("2013-08-02", "2014-06-13", "2015-09-03", "2016-06-12", "2016-09-27", "2017-05-30", "2017-05-30", "2017-09-14", "2017-09-14", "2017-12-02", "2018-03-29", "2018-06-05", "2018-10-19", "2019-02-27", "2019-06-04", "2019-08-28", "2019-10-22", "2020-02-04", "2020-06-06", "2020-08-26", "2020-10-23", "2021-02-01", "2021-06-15", "2021-08-03"),
  val = c(0.1470, 0.0623, 1.4600, 0.1810, 0.0509, 0.0801, 0.0801, 0.0999, 0.0980, 0.0820, 0.0698, 0.0884, 0.1060, 0.1010, 0.0984, 0.1050, 0.1100, 0.0980, 0.1000, 0.1090, 0.1050, 0.0662, 0.0944, 0.1220))
```

Comment: Not quite. The trouble is that the increases need to be progressive but not necessarily consecutive. For example, Row 16 should be TRUE because rows 11, 12, 14, and 16 progressively increase. Row 20 should be false because even though there are technically four increases, there isn't any grouping of 4 points in that set of 6 that progressively increases.

Comment: Could you define a "progressive increase" based on the direction of the slope of a linear model fit with date and val?